# Removing Absolute Position from jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've had a good search around StackOverflow and have not specifically come across this problem or found a fix to it.

What I want to do is be able to remove the following from the **ui-datepicker-div** of the jQuery UI Date Picker > https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

On the div it sets the following inline style

**style="position: absolute; top: 557px; left: 20px; z-index: 6; display: block;"**

I've had a good look around myself and cannot find away to get rid of this totally. If anyone knows how or has any ideas it would be great to know.

Thanks,
Glen

Comment: Can I know what is the issue and what you want to do?

Comment: I want to remove 

style="position: absolute; top: 557px; left: 20px; z-index: 6; display: block;"